# Posting form in Spring Boot +thymeleaf using jQuery

Tags: jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to posting form using jQuery.  I saw many tutorial but any works in my cas. So now i'm trying from the simples cases.

Now when I submit my form I woudl like to show message in console :

```
$("#new-period-form").submit(function (event) {
   console.log("Form submitted");
});
```

But this event newer occured.

```
<form action="#" id="new-period-form"
      th:object="${currentPeriodForm}" method="post">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text"
               id="period"              
               th:field="*{period}"
               pattern="^((19|20)\d\d)-(0?[1-9]|1[012])$"/>
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="period">Text...</label>
        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a valid format</span>

    </div>
    <input id="submit-new-period" type="submit"  value="save"> SUBMIT</input>
</form>
```

I noticied thatmapping /admin/newperiod is never invoked.  Submit  button send request directly to main page ( sow at beginning I was havins all times  errors of POST not allowed).

What I do wrong ?? :(

Comment: Two questions: Have you configured Spring (/admin/newperiod) controller to accept POST requests? Your form has the action "#". Why not /admin/newperiod?

Comment: yes. Controller admin/newperiod accept post ( postman test OK ).  for action:   I was trying to use th:action. /admin/newperiod so I didn't change this parameter.  The problem is not  to send directly request  to /admin/newperiod .. but catch it by JQuery to can do $("anotherdiv").load(...)

Comment: After this page is loaded in browser, open firebug tool to check you form action attribute. Does it have `#` or `/admin/newperoid`. What error do you see in browser console and IDE console?

Answer (score 3):

To make it work you just need to do few small changes.

1. In your submit button change the type to button, as you will handle it now with jquery

   ```
   <input id="submit-new-period" type="button"  value="save"> SUBMIT</input>
   ```
2. Create an event click for that button and attach a jquery function similar to this.

   ```
   $(function() {
       $('#submit-new-period').click(saveForm);
   });


   function saveForm(){
       $.ajax({
           method: "POST",
           url: "/your/action/endpoint",
           data: $('#idYourForm').serialize(),
           success: function(status){
               if(status) {
                   //here you check the response from your controller and add your business logic
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```
3. Remember in your controller add the annotation **@ResponseBody** as you are going to handle it by JS

Answer (score 0):

OK I was find the solution.
I dont know  why exactly it works like that.. but...

```
$(document).on('click', '#button-new-period', function(e) {
           var url = "/admin/gestion-period-new";
            $.ajax({
                   type : "GET",
                   url : "/admin/gestion-period-new",
                   timeout : 100000,
                   dataType: "html",
                   success : function(data) {
                       **$("#content-period").replaceWith(data);
                        window.componentHandler.upgradeDom();**
                        },
                   error : function(e) {
                       console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                   },
                   done : function(e) {
                       console.log("DONE");
                   }
               });
               e.preventDefault();
 });
```

What is  still a secret for me, that why this works :

```
                   $("#content-period").replaceWith(data);
                    window.componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

And this not :

```
 $("#content-period").load(url);
 window.componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Controller for load new period form

```
@RequestMapping("gestion-period-new")
public String gestionPeriodNew(CurrentPeriodForm currentPeriodForm) {
    return View.PAGE_ADMIN_CONTENT_GESTION_PERIOD_NEW;
}
```

And   View.PAGE_ADMIN_CONTENT_GESTION_PERIOD_NEW

```
public static final String PAGE_ADMIN_CONTENT_GESTION_PERIOD_NEW = "admin-page/gestion-period :: content-new-period";
```

Comment: can you share the code of your controller where you make the load call? where "url" is calling

Comment: voila.. but please noticed that LOAD  works like a function. So, the form is correctly display on the screen.  I can  write  the console.log after too. But  componentHandler called after that doesn't work